# Openlayers - Only display layers above a certain zoom level

Tags: html, if-statement, vector, openlayers, layer

I am working on an open layers map with different vector layers. I would like to add the function, that a certain vector layer is only displayed at a specific zoom value, for example at zoom >= 18. I tried it with the function minZoom and minScale / maxScale, but it didn't work. The vector layer I would like to display at zoom level >= 18 is called "dach layer". I also tried to solve it with an if function:

```
// dach layer anzeigen versuch
const dach = document.getElementById('dach');
dach.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("dach");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    if (map.getZoom() > 17) {
      dachLayer.setMap(map);
      //hitzeLayer.setVisible(true);
    }
   } else {
      //hitzeLayer.setVisible(false);
      dachLayer.setMap(undefined);
    }
});
```

This is the code I use:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Stamen from 'ol/source/Stamen';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import Vector from 'ol/source/Vector';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Circle from 'ol/style/Circle';
import Fill from 'ol/style/Fill';
import Stroke from 'ol/style/Stroke';
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import {
  fromLonLat,
  toLonLat
} from 'ol/proj';
import sync from 'ol-hashed';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import {
  circular
} from 'ol/geom/Polygon';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import Control from 'ol/control/Control';
import * as olProj from 'ol/proj';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

// define the map
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([16.37, 48.2]),
    zoom: 13
  })
});

sync(map);

//Adresssuche
const searchResultSource = new Vector();
const searchResultLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: searchResultSource
});

searchResultLayer.setStyle(new Style({
  image: new Circle({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 1)'
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#000000',
      width: 1.25
    }),
    radius: 15
  })
}));

var element = document.getElementById('search');
element.addEventListener('keydown', listenerFunction);

function listenerFunction(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://photon.komoot.de/api/?q=' + element.value + '&limit=3');
    xhr.onload = function () {
      const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      const geoJsonReader = new GeoJSON({
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
      });
      searchResultSource.clear();
      const features = geoJsonReader.readFeatures(json);
      console.log(features);
      searchResultSource.addFeatures(features);
      if (!searchResultSource.isEmpty()) {
        map.getView().fit(searchResultSource.getExtent(), {
          maxZoom: 18,
          duration: 500
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.send();


  }
}

//OpenStreetMap
const OSMbaseLayer = new TileLayer({
  type: 'base',
  source: new OSM()
});

// Statellit
const satellitLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    attributions: ['Powered by Esri', 'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
    attributionsCollapsible: false,
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 30
  })
});

//shape
const dachLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new Vector({
    name: 'dach',
    url: 'data/dach.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  })
});

dachLayer.setStyle(new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'brown'
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'brown',
    width: 0.25
  }),
}));

// Layer hinzufügen
map.addLayer(OSMbaseLayer);
map.addLayer(searchResultLayer);
dachLayer.setZIndex(15);

// dach layer anzeigen
const dach = document.getElementById('dach');
dach.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("dach");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    dachLayer.setMap(map);
    //hitzeLayer.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    //hitzeLayer.setVisible(false);
    dachLayer.setMap(undefined);
  }
}); 

// Get the OSMbase Base-Button
const OSMbase = document.getElementById('OSMbase');
OSMbase.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  //contr.style.color = 'ffffff';
  //Andere Layer entfernen
  map.removeLayer(satellitLayer);
  map.removeLayer(searchResultLayer);
  //OSM Layer hinzufügen
  map.addLayer(OSMbaseLayer);
  map.addLayer(searchResultLayer);
});

// Get the satellit Base-Button
const satellit = document.getElementById('satellit');
satellit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  //Andere Layer entfernen
  map.removeLayer(OSMbaseLayer);
  map.removeLayer(searchResultLayer);
  //Satelliten Layer hinzufügen
  map.addLayer(satellitLayer);
  map.addLayer(searchResultLayer);
});
```

Comment: minZoom should work and is much simpler to use.  Just remember that like maxResolution minZoom is exclusive so to include level 18 you would need to set `minZoom: 17.9999`  Here is a simple example switching on at level 4 https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-4tyl6

Comment: I tried it with the minZoom function, but it doesn't work. The layer is still shown at lower zoom levels.

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using?

Comment: I think the newest one, so v.6

Comment: This is the layer I want to show at zoom level > 18, and how I edited it:
`const dachLayer = new VectorLayer({
 minZoom: 17.9999,
 source: new Vector({
    name: 'dach',
    url: 'data/dachnotnull.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  })
});`

Answer (score 0):

The `getZoom()` method is derived from the View module:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#getZoom

The following works:

```
dach.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("dach");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    if (map.getview().getZoom() > 17) {
      dachLayer.setMap(map);
      //hitzeLayer.setVisible(true);
    }
   } else {
      //hitzeLayer.setVisible(false);
      dachLayer.setMap(undefined);
    }
});
```

At the same time you might want to look into the 'moveend' event on the map to listen for zoom changes instead of click:

```
map.on('moveend', () => {
// do kewl things
}
```

Comment: I just tired it but the code didn't work :/
The vector layer doesn't appear at all

Comment: Created a JSFiddle, works fine here:

https://jsfiddle.net/84j2q05t/

Removed your checkbox though, too lazy to put that in the HTML.

Comment: It somehow only switches the layers when I click on the + zoom button, however if I zoom in without clicking the + zoom button, nothing happens. So I need to insert the map.on('moveend',... to make it appear when I zoom in without clicking the + button? Did I get that right?

Comment: At the moment you're listening for a click-event on a specific element. I assume this is on the Map. So if you're zooming with your mouse, the conditional statement will not trigger before you click inside the div.

If you remove the click event, and replace it with a 'moveend'-event as i stated above, you will trigger the conditional statement `if (map.getview().getZoom() > 17)` at the end of a "move". I assume this will work as you expect.

Comment: okey, I don't get it, it's not working, I tried replacing the 'click' with 'moveend', but somehow the layer disappears

Comment: Please post all of your code to a jsfiddle if you don' mind, and share it. Will be easier to spot any mistakes.